# sp_dts_getfolder isn't in my MSDB database, any ideas why?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

We're currently moving our applications from a SQL 2005 to a SQL 2008 R2 database and everything has gone well(ish) but now one of our applications calls a stored proc called sp_dts_getfolder which is meant to be in the MSDB database.

But it doesn't seem to be there at all, did we not install something or is this no longer a valid stored procedure in 2008 R2? What replaced it?

Comment: No it's a brand new install, I was under the impression this was a standard MSDB stored procedure?

Comment: Do you have any maintenance plans?

Comment: @Arion not that I am aware off, that's taken care off by the SQL DBA's I think. This stored proc is being called by our code, I'm trying to track down the actual line that does it though.. it's hiding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why I think it can be something about the maintenance plans is because on
msdn it states:

> If the account that the SQL Server Agent runs under on the target
>   server (TSX) is not a member of the sysadmin fixed server role on the
>   master server (MSX), to import a distributed maintenance plan, the
>   account must be granted the following permission on the master server.
>
> .......
>
> If this permission is not
>   granted, the following error will appear in the SQL Server Agent log
>   on the target server when the multiserver SQL Server Agent Job that
>   runs the maintenance plan is refreshed by the target server:
>
> "Failed to import Maintenance Plan  from <
>   NameOfMasterServer>:
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: While trying to
>   find a folder on SQL an OLE DB error was encountered with error code
>   0x80040E09 (The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object
>   'sp_dts_getfolder', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.)"
>
> After these permissions are changed, each existing distributed
>   maintenance plan must be reloaded on the target server. Make a small
>   change to each plan and save. This will force the target server to
>   reload the maintenance plan from the master server. By default, the
>   target server will update jobs from the master server every 60
>   seconds. There will be a minimum delay of 120 seconds after you save
>   the maintenance plan before it appears and can be run on the target
>   server.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187658%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) is the link to read about it

You should also looked at this [kb](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127). This is a fix from Microsoft regarding this problem.

After some investigation I found that going from sql 2005 to sql 2008 there are some changes in the system store procedures

> Now the twist in the story is, since SSIS 2005 has grown up from DTS,
>   the system tables and system stored procedures use a naming convention
>   like "dts" in its name as you can see in first column of table below.
>   With SSIS 2008, the SSIS team has standardize the naming convention
>   and uses "ssis" in its name as you can see in the second column of the
>   table below. So if you are using these system tables or system stored
>   procedure in your code and upgrading to SSIS 2008, your code will
>   break unless you change your code to accommodate this new naming
>   convention.

So the [msdb].[dbo].[sp_dts_getfolder] is actually changed to [msdb].[dbo].[sp_ssis_getfolder].

You can find all of the other procedure changed and some more information in the article [Best Practice #17 - Names of system tables and procedures have changed between SSIS 2005 and SSIS 2008](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1893/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-design-best-practices/)

Comment: I'm not sure that would be my solution, but I'll ask the DBA's to add a maintenance plan and maybe that will create the SP's..

Comment: Okay there is already a maintenance plan on that server.. still no stored procedures though?

Comment: Updated the answer see the link in the answer

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't give me any insight into why the stored procedures don't exist in the 2008 database at all.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: We found the answer at the same time ;), I needed to recompile my application with the new DTS runtimes that shipped with 2008 R2 and everything starts working. All related to the info posted above.. thanks

Comment: Glad I could help.